# ObservableCollection caching and binding

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, observablecollection

This code populates an ObservableCollection for ListView binding and it works perfectly. It involves querying a many-to-many database implementation. I am now trying to improve performance by caching lists which have already been loaded. Here is the present code:

```
public void List_for_Display(int _id)
    {            
        IEnumerable<Central> items;//central is the many-to-many db implementation
        items = conn.Query<Central>("select * from Central where _id = ?", _id.ToString());
        Cat_V.Clear();//this is the property to which the ListView is bound
        foreach (Central in items)
        {
            var top1 = (from q in conn.Table<Topic>()//Topic is of the tables tahat is linked
                        where q.id == d._id
                        select q).FirstOrDefault();
            Cat_V.Add(top1);
        }
    }
```

This is the binding property:

```
  private ObservableCollection<Topic> cat_V = new ObservableCollection<Topic>();
    public ObservableCollection<Topic> Cat_V
    {
        get { return cat_V; }
        set
        {
            cat_V = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

To cache the already loaded ObservableCollections, I declare an array as as a variable:

```
Public ObservableCollection<Topic> [] Saving ;
```

Saving is initialized to to the proper size, and each element is initialized with `Saving[_index] = new ObservableCollection<Topic>();`The infromation is properly stored in the ObservableCollections in the array. This is the code:

```
public void List_for_Display(int _cat_ind, int _cat_id)
    {            
        if (Saving[_cat_ind] == null)
        {

            Saving[_cat_ind] = new ObservableCollection<Topic>();
            IEnumerable<Central> items;
            items= conn.Query<Central>("select * from Central where cat_id = ?", _cat_id.ToString());
            foreach (CenTab1 d in items)
            {
                var top1 = (from q in conn.Table<Topic>()
                            where q.id == d.top_id
                            select q).FirstOrDefault();
                Saving[_cat_ind].Add(top1);                    
            }

        }
        Cat_V = Saving[_cat_ind];
    }
```

The ui is loaded properly the first time by the above function, but not after the first assignment. OnPropertyChanged is raised but the ui is not updated unlike the first version.

Thank you!

Update:

The ListView binding: `ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Cat_V}"`

The OnPropertyChanged method:

```
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: 1. How ListView's  DataSource property is bound to the `Cat_V` property? 2. Show the code of the Method `OnPropertyChanged`. I think it is defined as  a method, not an event, right?

Comment: I added the code in the update.

Comment: I now have the code working by clearing the binded ObsevableCollection and adding with an iterator each item of Saving[i], but it would be nice to know what is happening and why the above code is not working.

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem, I have written a small project to implement your idea, and the binding and the notification are working. It helps if you can provide a minimal project to recreate the problem.